# Why i can't catch left button click event?

Tags: silverlight

I wrote some simple application that need to do something in case there is some Mouse Left Button Down event.

I dont understand why i dont stop on the breakpoint that i have in the method "MouseLeftButtonDown_Event"

The xaml:

```
<UserControl 
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" >

        <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleTarget" Height="50" Width="50" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown_Event" />


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you post the event handler code and indicate where you are setting the break point.

Comment: private void MouseLeftButtonDown_Event( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
        {
            // Do somthing 
        }

Comment: Use the "edit" link to add it into your question where it will be properly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similiar problem once, and the problem was that only the topmost objects catch the click, among other things.  Try this in your constructor and see if it helps.

```
LayoutRoot.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, MouseLeftButtonDown_Event, true);
```

The *true* at the end will mean that the element will handle the event, even if something else has already done so.

Hope this helps!